# mod_alias RedirectMatch all urls except one

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, apache2, mod-alias

i would like to redirect all Pages to a maintainence site with the path

> /software/web/app.php/update

So i need to redirect all pages, except the site itself as otherwise i would get a redirect loop which means i need a rule which matches that path and negate it. Sounds easy, but doesnt work for me.

> RedirectMatch (?!/software/web/app.php/update) h*tp://abc.de/software/web/app.php/update
>
> RedirectMatch ^(?!/software/web/app.php/update)$ h*tp://abc.de/software/web/app.php/update
>
> RedirectMatch ^/software/web/app.php(?!/update)$ h*tp://abc.de/software/web/app.php/update

Non of these helps. I tried almost everything i found here and on other sites, but after hours of trial, i surrender and kindly ask for your help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1):

You could do this with just a simple RewriteRule prefixed with a condition:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^/software/web/app.php/update$)
RewriteRule .* /software/web/app.php/update [R=307]
```

If the maintenance site contains things like images then you will need to exclude those images from the rule, for example:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^/images/maintaining.jpg$)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^/software/web/app.php/update$)
RewriteRule .* /software/web/app.php/update [R=307]
```

If you are redirecting to another site, then the rule can be used to put the entire URL:

```
RewriteRule .* http://example.com/software/web/app.php/update [R=307]
```

For reference, the `[R=307]` at the end of the RewriteRule states that the browser would see the URL rewritten, but that it is a temporary redirect.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does your answer imply that it cant be done with a RedirectMatch?

Comment: Hi. I've not really used RedirectMatch, I just figured this is a good alternative. As RedirectMatch uses PCRE, it makes "negating" the string tricky - negative look-ahead is your best option. Perhaps try the following match: `^(?!/software/web/app.php/update).*`? Not putting this as an answer, as I can't test it with RewriteMatch, but it works when I run it through grep.

Comment: To match only sites which are part of app.php, i did it like that:

`RedirectMatch ^(?!/software/web/app.php/update)(?=/software/web/app.php).* h*tp://abc.de/software/web/app.php/update`

Or like you suggested with mod_rewrite:

`RewriteEngine on` `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^/software/web/app\.php/update$)` `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/software/web/app\.php.*$` `RewriteRule .* /software/web/app.php/update [R=307]`

This way all other files (jpg,css,js) work without any problems. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Even easier:
`RedirectMatch ^/software/web/app.php(?!/update).* http://abc.de/software/web/app.php/update`